# How to create REST URLs without verbs?

Tags: rest, restful-url

I'm struggling to determine how to design restful URLs.  I'm all for the restful approach of using URLs with nouns and not verbs don't understand how to do this.

We are creating a service to implement a financial calculator.  The calculator takes a bunch of parameters that we will upload via a CSV file.  The use cases would involve:

1. Upload new parameters
2. Get the latest parameters
3. Get parameters for a given business date
4. Make a set of parameters active
5. Validate a set of parameters

I gather the restful approach would be to have the following type URLs:

```
/parameters
/parameters/12-23-2009
```

You could achieve the first three use cases with:

1. POST where you include the parameter file in the post request
2. GET of first URL
3. GET of second URL

But how do you do the 4th and 5th use case without a verb?  Wouldn't you need URLs like:

```
/parameters/ID/activate
/parameters/ID/validate
```

??

Comment: I prefer PATCH rather than POST for partial update.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
PUT /parameters/activation HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; encoding=UTF-8
Content-Length: 18

{ "active": true }
```

Comment: Good suggestion.  As we could have multiple sets of parameters we would need something like POST /parameters/id/activation ...

Comment: `POST` is OK if you need to perform a "procedure" like verify the parameters every time you send a request. But when you modify the (application) state of the resource, you actually **update** the existing resource, not create some new resource or post a processing request.

Comment: `POST` is akin to insert and update, while `PUT` is akin to update only.

Comment: @Justice "active" is a property of resource, so it should be `PUT`, not `POST`ed. See the similar "draft" property of the definitely RESTful Atom Publishing Protocol.

Comment: However, you are right in that this arguably should be modelled as a `PUT`.

Comment: PUT is for creating a new resource, or placing (in whole, not in part) a new resource at a particular URL. I don't see how PUT fits this case.

Comment: Actually, `POST` vs `PUT` is not exactly like `insert` vs `update`. `PUT` updates the resource corresponding to the given path, or creates a new resource corresponding to the given path. `POST` creates a new resource somewhere. For example, `PUT /blog/posts/3/comments/5` will update the appropriate comment, while `POST /blog/posts/3/comments` will create a new `comment` resource (and should return the path to the new resource in the response).

Comment: Yeah, I meant to say something like that about PUT, but the words came out slightly ambiguous. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Justice @Breton The more important difference is that `PUT` is idempotent while `POST` is not. Usually you should put as much constraints on what you provide as the result as possible. Sticking with `PUT` gives more information to the client of the service.

Comment: The resource could also have been /parameters/status and the body of the request could have been just "active". That way you are somehow placing a whole new resource to a particular URL.

Comment: PUT is only for (re)placing whole ressources. If you only pass one attribute, like you did with "active", you should use PATCH.

Comment: @freshfelicio Although the answer using `PUT` was the best one in 2009, the `PATCH` method is now coming into some sort of practice. The trouble is the content of the `PATCH` request. Something like https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6902 (http://jsonpatch.com/) might work.

Comment: should probably be patch.

Answer (score 1007):

General principles for good URI design:

- **Don't** use query parameters to alter state
- **Don't** use mixed-case paths if you can help it; lowercase is best
- **Don't** use implementation-specific extensions in your URIs (.php, .py, .pl, etc.)
- **Don't** fall into [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) with your URIs
- **Do** limit your URI space as much as possible
- **Do** keep path segments short
- **Do** prefer either `/resource` or `/resource/`; create 301 redirects from the one you don't use
- **Do** use query parameters for sub-selection of a resource; i.e. pagination, search queries
- **Do** move stuff out of the URI that should be in an HTTP header or a body

(Note: I did not say "RESTful URI design"; URIs are essentially opaque in REST.)

General principles for HTTP method choice:

- **Don't** ever use GET to alter state; this is a great way to have the Googlebot ruin your day
- **Don't** use PUT unless you are updating an entire resource
- **Don't** use PUT unless you can also legitimately do a GET on the same URI
- **Don't** use POST to retrieve information that is long-lived or that might be reasonable to cache
- **Don't** perform an operation that is not [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) with PUT
- **Do** use GET for as much as possible
- **Do** use POST in preference to PUT when in doubt
- **Do** use POST whenever you have to do something that feels RPC-like
- **Do** use PUT for classes of resources that are larger or hierarchical
- **Do** use DELETE in preference to POST to remove resources
- **Do** use GET for things like calculations, unless your input is large, in which case use POST

General principles of web service design with HTTP:

- **Don't** put metadata in the body of a response that should be in a header
- **Don't** put metadata in a separate resource unless including it would create significant overhead
- **Do** use the appropriate status code
- `201 Created` after creating a resource; resource **must** exist at the time the response is sent
- `202 Accepted` after performing an operation successfully or creating a resource asynchronously
- `400 Bad Request` when someone does an operation on data that's clearly bogus; for your application this could be a validation error; generally reserve 500 for uncaught exceptions
- `401 Unauthorized` when someone accesses your API either without supplying a necessary `Authorization` header or when the credentials within the `Authorization` are invalid; don't use this response code if you aren't expecting credentials via an `Authorization` header.
- `403 Forbidden` when someone accesses your API in a way that might be malicious or if they aren't authorized
- `405 Method Not Allowed` when someone uses POST when they should have used PUT, etc
- `413 Request Entity Too Large` when someone attempts to send you an unacceptably large file
- `418 I'm a teapot` [when attempting to brew coffee with a teapot](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2324#section-2.3.2)
- **Do** use caching headers whenever you can
- `ETag` headers are good when you can easily reduce a resource to a hash value
- `Last-Modified` should indicate to you that keeping around a timestamp of when resources are updated is a good idea
- `Cache-Control` and `Expires` should be given sensible values
- **Do** everything you can to honor caching headers in a request (`If-None-Modified`, `If-Modified-Since`)
- **Do** use redirects when they make sense, but these should be rare for a web service

With regard to your specific question, POST should be used for #4 and #5.  These operations fall under the "RPC-like" guideline above.  For #5, remember that POST does not necessarily have to use `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  This could just as easily be a JSON or CSV payload.

Comment: 413 is intended for the size of the request you are being sent so that you can politely reject someone sending you gigs of data, often in conjunction with 411 so you force people to tell you how much is being sent. For the example given against 413, I think 400 would be a more appropriate response.

Comment: +1 since this is a great resource. However, it's a general resource and doesn't directly andwer the question. This ideally should include an additional paragraph with a specific answer.

Comment: @GarryShutler Good catch, you're absolutely right. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: In my opinion, it's either /resource or /resource/ - no redirects from the wrong one. Additionally, one should use URIs with/without the trailing slash consistently throughout the API.

Comment: @finishingmove Despite popular belief, REST is not just about APIs. In an API, yes, I'd agree, redirects may be counter-productive. In a RESTful site intended to be accessed by browser, they are not. Not all clients will follow redirects automatically. The ones that do may behave differently, depending on the HTTP method used by the endpoint in a redirect scenario. Browsers will be consistent, however. That said, you should still not use both. One or the other. In an API, it should be a failure condition to use the wrong one, with a clear error message indicating what you probably meant to do.

Comment: I like to use **PATCH** over **PUT** for partial update. For example, I use `PATCH /user/:id` for updating an user, because users are seldom overwritten entirely but only part of them can be updated.
**PUT**, on the other hand, is used to overwrite something. For example, `PUT /user/:id/name` to overwrite an user's name.

Comment: Yes, you would only use **PUT** in cases where you're overwriting the whole object. However, I'd claim that either **PATCH** or **POST** are reasonable in the case of a partial update of a resource. **PATCH** is more clear in terms of what the operation is going to do, but because not all clients are even capable of issuing a **PATCH** request, it's entirely appropriate to allow a **POST** instead, and I might even go so far as to advocate that a **POST** should always be allowed as a fallback if **PATCH** is used.

Comment: Thanks Bob-- these are the rules I felt make sense, but I keep having to second guess myself because of other people insisting on a more RESTful approach. But what is you opinion on a case where a large amount of data needs to be sent to URI to retrieve collection results which is long lived data and cacheable?  Would you break your principal "Don't use POST to retrieve information that is long-lived or that might be reasonable to cache" or would you use two URIs and send the data in a POST which returns an ID that can be used in a GET?

Comment: @BobThule The larger the cacheable payload, the more important it is to use a **GET** to retrieve it. There's no reason the contents of that payload could not be created, appended, modified, or otherwise altered by the results of a separate **POST** operation as long as you consider potential cache invalidation issues. I'd recommend against returning an ID in the body of a **POST** response to get you over to a separate **GET** request. That's what the `Location` header is for.

Comment: That's a very good an comprehensive list, the problem is that I find it hard to avoid this one: "Don't fall into RPC with your URIs" in complex application. When you need to perform more than one action on one URI, it becomes unclear what a POST request does, if you don't include a verb in it, to describe the action. POST is very general. If you look at Twitter's REST API, a POST on the resource URI is not enough, hence they expose URIs like: POST blocks/create, POST blocks/destroy. Does this make it a bad REST API?

Comment: I don't personally think Twitter's API is a good exemplar for a RESTful API. It's much less egregious than many other supposedly REST APIs, but there are better options for sure. The main problem with Twitter's API design is that the logical action is in the URL instead of the payload. An action to be performed is not a resource. They should have treated the block list as a resource collection (collections are just resources which are themselves made up of other resources) and then operated on that collection with either a **PATCH** or a **POST** with a parameter indicating a 'create' action.

Comment: +1 for 409 errors.  A 400 error is something that could be resolved by sufficient client-side validation.  A 409 clarifies that the request itself was acceptable and consistent, but conflicts with some aspect of server state (usually concurrency controls, but theoretically any non-input constraint).

Comment: Very good tips, but I can't find how this answer the question.

Comment: @Dherik Read the last paragraph.

Comment: Hi Bob. I really could not understand how answer the question "Wouldn't you need URLs like: ??". Yes, no or maybe? Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Whenever it looks like you need a new verb, think about turning that verb into a noun instead. For example, turn 'activate' into 'activation', and 'validate' into 'validation'.

But just from what you've written I'd say your application has much bigger problems.

Any time a resource called 'parameter' is proposed, it should send up red flags in every project team member's mind. 'parameter' can literally apply to any resource; it's not specific enough.

What exactly does a 'parameter' represent? Probably a number of different things, each of which should have a separate resource dedicated to it.

Another way to get at this - when you discuss your application with end users (those who presumably know little about programming) what are the words they themselves use repeatedly?

Those are the words you should be designing your application around.

If you haven't yet had this conversion with prospective users - stop everything right now and don't write another line of code until you do! Only then will your team have an idea of what needs to be built.

I know nothing about financial software, but if I had to guess, I'd say some of the resources might go by names such as "Report", "Payment", "Transfer", and "Currency".

There are a number of good books on this part of the software design process. Two I can recommend are [Domain Driven Design](http://books.google.com/books?id=7dlaMs0SECsC&dq=domain+driven+design&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=RITjSqCbNIeqtgPQ7NCwBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=&f=false) and [Analysis Patterns](http://books.google.com/books?id=4V8pZmpwmBYC&dq=analysis+patterns&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=a4TjSuXLHI-OswOZ6LiwBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CBUQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=&f=false).

Comment: This is a really good point. It's easy to miss if you're in the state of mind for processing formal logic and reasoning. It doesn't matter what X is as long as it fits together with the other parts in a valid way. Human factors just slip away.

Comment: Sometimes I find it useful to convert the words into a "processing resource" like "activator" or "validator".  As per RFC 2616 POST can be used to "Provide a block of data...to a data-handling process"

Comment: Understood.  In this case users do refer to the data as "parameters" (or "risk parameters" or something similar).  The list of parameters do contain many different types of settings but the parameters are always uploaded as a whole set (in a CSV file).

Comment: @Marcus - that sounds like a very unusual case. Maybe if you explained what your app does in more detail, we'd be able to offer better suggestions for identifying resources.

Comment: "when you discuss your application with end users what are the words they themselves use repeatedly?"  ... and what if they're all verbs? XD

Answer (score 11):

The design of your URLs has nothing to do with whether your application is RESTful or not. The phrase "RESTful URLs" is therefore nonsense.

I think you should do some more reading on what REST actually is. REST treats the URLS as opaque, and as such doesn't know what's in them, whether there are verbs or nouns or whatever. You might still want to design your URLs, but that's about UI, not REST.

That said, let's get to your question: The last two cases are not RESTful and don't fit into any kind of restful scheme. Those are what you might call RPC. If you're serious about REST, you'll have to rethink how your application works from the ground up. Either that or abandon REST and just do your app as an RPC app.

Hrmmm maybe not.

The idea here is that you have to treat everything as a resource, so once a set of parameters has a URL you can refer to it from, you just add:

```
GET [parametersurl]/validationresults

POST [paramatersurl]
body: {command:"activate"}
```

But again, that activate thing is RPC, not REST.

Comment: You state an interesting point here. Can you elaborate a little further how the RESTful approach for something like this would be?

Comment: I've spent a bit of time reading the responses here, and I think justice might be on to something. he models individual properties of your parameters object as individual resources, and uses the PUT verb to replace the contents of that property at that resource. This is modelling the state of each object as a collection of resources, and modifying state as placing or removing or modifying the resource.  As for validation- You just need a resource that magically states whether the parameters are valid or not, as above in my answer. That would be fine, as long as that has no side effects.

Comment: Provided of course, that what "Activate" does is merely set a single property to true. If it has to do anything else, then it's still not RESTful, and I'm not sure how you'd model it RESTfully.

Comment: I don't think you can say the last two cases are not RESTful. In effect Activate and Validate are just indirect ways of saying the resource is changing to a new state in a state machine.  REST is quite capable of modeling this.

Comment: @Darrel, I think you point out a part of REST that may be challenging for many people who are new to REST. How might you go about implementing a "Validate resource x" operation?  I think the challenging thing is that it is an operation that could result in a change in state, but the new state is a result of the request being made.

Answer (score 6):

The activate and validate requirements are situations where you are attempting to change the state of a resource.  It is no different that making an order "completed", or some other request "submitted".  There are numerous ways to model these kinds of state change but one that I find that often works is to create collection resources for resources of the same state and then to move the resource between the collections to affect the state.

e.g.  Create some resources such as,

```
/ActiveParameters
/ValidatedParameters
```

If you want to make a set of parameters active, then add that set to the ActiveParameters collection.  You could either pass the set of parameters as an entity body, or you could pass an url as a query parameter, as follows:

```
POST /ActiveParameters?parameter=/Parameters/{Id}
```

The same thing can be done with the /ValidatedParameters.  If the Parameters are not valid then the server can return "Bad Request" to the request to add the parameters to collection of validated parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following Meta resource and methods.

Make parameters active and/or validate them:

```
> PUT /parameters/<id>/meta HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> Content-Type: application/json
> Connection: close
>
> {'active': true, 'require-valid': true}
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Connection: close
<
```

Check if the parameters are active and valid:

```
> GET /parameters/<id>/meta HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> Connection: close
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Connection: close
<
< {
<     'active': true,
<     'require-valid': true,
<     'valid': {'status': false, 'reason': '...'}
< }
<
```

Comment: As far as I understand, the question is about the naming of the restful URLs, not about the  functionality, isn't it?

Comment: A question confined to "RESTful URLs" is a bad question and should not be answered. The question should instead be expanded to consider "RESTful resources, with associated methods and URLs" - and answered as such.

Comment: As I understood it, the question was about the URL naming conventions **and** the HTTP methods the named resource should respond to.

Answer (score 1):

I feel a bit sad to see that after more than 10 years there is no answer really stating how such a thing as requested in the OP could be designed in a REST architecture, hence I feel the need to do this now.

First things first, what is REST?! The acronym REST or ReST stands for "Representational State Transfer" and defines the exchange of a resource's state in a certain representation format. The representation format is tide to the negotiated media type. In the case of `application/html` the representation format may be a stream of HTML formatted text content that is rendered in the browser, probably after applying some stylesheet formatting to position certain elements at certain locations.

REST is in principle a generalization of the browsable Web we all know, though targets all kinds of applications and not only browsers. Therefore, by design, the same concepts that apply to the Web also apply to a REST architecture. A question like how to achieve something in a "RESTful" way resolves around answering the question how to achieve something on a Web page and then apply the same concepts onto the application layer.

A Web based calculator may usually start off with some "page" that allows you to input some values to calculate before sending the entered data to the server. In HTML this is usually achieved via HTML `<form>` elements that teaches a client on the available parameters to set, the target location to send the request to as well as the representation format to apply upon sending the input data. This can i.e. look like this:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/../someResource" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
      <label for="firstNumber">First number:</label>
      <input type="number" id="firstNumber" name="firstNumber"/>

      <label for="secondNumber">Second number:</label>
      <input type="number" id="secondNumber" name="secondNumber"/>

      <input type="submit" value="Add numbers"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The sample above i.e. states that there are two input fields that can be filled out either by the user or by some other automata, and that upon invoking the submit input element the browser takes care of formatting the input data into a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` representation format that is sent to the mentioned target location via the specified HTTP request method, `POST` in this case. If we enter `1` into the `firstNumber` input field and `2` into the `secondNumber` input field, the browser will generate a representation of `firstNumber=1&secondNumber=2` and send this as the body payload of the actual request to the target resource.

The raw HTTP request issued to the server therefore may look like this:

```
POST /../someResource
Host: www.acme.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 28
Accept: application/html

firstNumber=1&secondNumber=2
```

The server may perform the calculation and respond with a further HTML page that contains the result of the calculation, as the request indicated that the client understands this format.

As Breton pointed already out there is no such thing as a "RESTful" URL or URI. A URI/URL is its own kind of thing and should not convey any meaning to a client/user. In the calculator sample above a user simply isn't interested where to send the data to it is just interested in that upon triggering the submit input field the request is sent. All the required information needed to perform the task should already be given by the server.

A browser also might not be aware of that the request is actually feeding a calculator with some input parameters, it could as well be some kind of an order form that returns just the next form representation to continue the ordering process or some totally different kind of resource. It simply performs what the HTML spec demands in such a case and it couldn't care less what the server is actually doing. This concept enables a browser to use the same representation format to do all kind of things such as ordering some stuff from your preferred online shop, chatting with your best friends, signing into an online account and so on.

The [affordance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIv9YR1bMwY&t=817) of certain elements, such in the submit input field case that is usually rendered as button, defines what you should to with it. In the case of a button or a link it basically tells you to click it. Other elements may convey different affordances. Such an affordance can also be expressed via [link-relations](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) as i.e. with `preload` annotated links that basically tell a client that it can already load the content of the linked resource in the background as the user will most likely grab this content next. Such link relations should of course be standardized or follow the extension mechanism for relation types as defined by [Web linking](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988#section-4.2).

These are the fundamental concept that are used on the Web and that should also be used in a REST architecture. According to "Uncle Bob" Robert C. Martin [an architecture is about intent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_TH-Y78tt4&t=860s) and the intention behind the REST architecture is the decoupling of clients from servers to allow servers to evolve freely in future without having to fear them breaking clients. This unfortunately requires a lot of discipline as it is so easy to introduce coupling or to add quick-fix solutions to get the job done and move on. As Jim Webber pointed out in a REST architecture you, as a service provider, should attempt to design an [domain application protocol similar to a text based computer game of the 70s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=7m01s) that clients will follow through until they reached the end of a process.

What plenty of so-called "REST" APIs unfortunately do in reality is everything but that. You see the exchange of mostly JSON based data that is specified in an API specific external documentation that is usually hard to dynamically integrate on the fly. The format how a request needs to look like are also hardcoded into the external documentation which lead to plenty of implementation interpreting URIs to [return predefined typs](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html) instead of using some common representation format that is negotiated upfront. This prevents servers from changing as clients now expect to receive a certain data format (note not representation format!) for predefined URIs. This custom data format exchange furthermore prevents clients from interacting with other APIs as the "data format" is usually tide to a specific API. We know this concept from the past from RPC technologies such as Corba, RMI or SOAP which we condemn as somehow evil, even though Peppol moved to it again by replacing AS2 with AS4 as default transfer protocol as of recently.

In regards to the actual question asked, sending data as csv file is nothing different than using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` representation or similar stuff. Jim Webber made it clear that after all [HTTP is just a transport protocol whose application domain is the transfer of documents over the Web](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=191s). Client and server should at least both support `text/csv` as defined in [RFC 7111](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7111). This CSV file could be generated as a consequence of processing a media type that defines form elements, a target element or attribute to send the request to as well as the HTTP method to perform the upload of the configuration.

There are a couple of media types that support forms such as [HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html), [HAL Forms](https://rwcbook.github.io/hal-forms/), [halform](http://halform.herokuapp.com/), [ion](https://ionspec.org/#forms) or [Hydra](http://www.hydra-cg.com/). I am currently, though, not aware of a media type that automatically can encode the input data into `text/csv` directly hence one might need to be defined and registered with [IANA's media type registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml).

The upload and download of the complete parameter set shouldn't be an issue I guess. As mentioned before, the target URI is not of relevance as a client will just use the URI to retrieve new content to process. Filtering by business date should also not be to difficult. Here the server should however the client with all the possibilities the client simply can chose from. In recent years GraphQL and RestQL evolved which introduce an SQL like language that can be targeted at a certain endpoint to get a filtered response. However, in a true REST sense this violates the idea behind REST as a) GraphQL i.e. only uses a single endpoint which somehow prevents optimal usage of caching and b) requires the knowledge of available fields upfrong, which may lead to introducing a coupling of clients to the base data model of the resource.

Activating or deactivating certain configuration parameters is simply a matter of triggering the hypermedia controls that provide this affordance. In HTML forms this could be a simple checkbox or a multi-line selection in a list or that kind. Depending on the form and what method it defines it could then potentially send the whole configuration via `PUT` or be smart about the changes done and only perform a partial update via `PATCH`. The latter one requires basically a calculaton of the change representation to the one updated and feed the server with the required steps to tranform the current representation into the desired one. According to the [PATH specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2) this has to be done within a transaction so that either all or none of the steps are applied.

HTTP allows and encourages a server to validate a received request upfront before applying the changes. For [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) the spec states:

> An origin server SHOULD verify that the PUT representation is
> consistent with any constraints the server has for the target
> resource that cannot or will not be changed by the PUT.  This is
> particularly important when the origin server uses internal
> configuration information related to the URI in order to set the
> values for representation metadata on GET responses.  When a PUT
> representation is inconsistent with the target resource, the origin
> server SHOULD either make them consistent, by transforming the
> representation or changing the resource configuration, or respond
> with an appropriate error message containing sufficient information
> to explain why the representation is unsuitable.  The 409 (Conflict)
> or 415 (Unsupported Media Type) status codes are suggested, with the
> latter being specific to constraints on Content-Type values.
>
> For example, if the target resource is configured to always have a
> Content-Type of "text/html" and the representation being PUT has a
> Content-Type of "image/jpeg", the origin server ought to do one of:
>
> a.  reconfigure the target resource to reflect the new media type;
>
> b.  transform the PUT representation to a format consistent with that
> of the resource before saving it as the new resource state; or,
>
> c.  reject the request with a 415 (Unsupported Media Type) response
> indicating that the target resource is limited to "text/html",
> perhaps including a link to a different resource that would be a
> suitable target for the new representation.
>
> HTTP does not define exactly how a PUT method affects the state of an
> origin server beyond what can be expressed by the intent of the user
> agent request and the semantics of the origin server response. ...

To sum this post up, you should either use an existing media type that allows you to teach a client about the required or supported input parameters, the target location to send the request to, the operation to use as well as the media-type the request has to be formatted in, or define your own one that you register with IANA. The latter might be necessary if you want to convert the input to `text/csv` and then upload the CSV representation to the server. The validation should occur before the changes are applied to the resource. The actual URI should not be of relevance to clients other than to determine where to send the request to and as such can be freely chosen by you, the service implementor. By following these steps you pretty much gain the freedom to change your server side at any time and clients will not break as a consequence if they support the used media-types.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Indeed the URI would have prevented `GET` requests from remaining idempotent.

---

For the validation however, the use of HTTP status codes to notify the validity of a request (to create a new or modify an existing 'parameter') would fit a Restful model.

Report back with a `400 Bad Request` status code if the data submitted is/are invalid and the request must be altered before being resubmitted ([HTTP/1.1 Status Codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)).

This relies on validating at submission time though, rather than deferring it as in your use-case. The other answers have suitable solutions to that scenario.

Comment: The URI is meant to be an identifier. Using a particular URL should not have side effects. Imagine what a proxy would do with that.

Comment: or google, for that matter. I once read a story about a webstore that had all their products deleted by google because of this kind of idiocy.

Answer (score 0):

In a REST environment, each URL is a unique resource. What are your resources? A financial calculator really doesn't have any obvious resources. You need to dig into what you are calling parameters and pull out the resources. For example, an amortization calendar for a loan might be a resource. The URL for the calendar might include start date, term (in months or years), period (when interest is compounded), interest rate, and initial principle. With all those values, you have a specific calendar of payments:

```
http://example.com/amort_cal/2009-10-20/30yrsfixed/monthly/5.00/200000
```

Now, I don't know what you are calculating, but your concept of a parameter list doesn't sound RESTful. As someone else said, your requirements above sound more XMLRPC. If you are trying for REST, you need nouns. Calculations are not nouns, they are verbs that act on nouns. You need to turn it around to pull the nouns out of your calcs.

Comment: I think it's a bit silly to use forward slashes here, what would be wrong with amort_cal?date=2009-10-20&type=30yrsfixed&period=monthly&rate=5.0&initialamount=200000 ? REST doesn't care as long as it's a resource. The URI spec *does* care though. How do you imagine relative links to work with a scheme like this?

Comment: You bring up a good point nonetheless. Do these "parameters" even need to be stored serverside? If it's just a one off calculation, why not just make a virtual space, where the parameters are in the URL. As long as you're not changing internal state, it should be fine.

Comment: What relative links? Relative to what? There is nothing that requires you to name your parameters in the way you state. REST involves resources, not executables with parameters. Also, you should look up SEO and ask me again why you might not want to use &foo=val&

Comment: SEO does not apply to a web service.

Comment: And "parameters" don't apply to a "resource". A resource is a single entity with a unique identifier. My url identifies a single resource. A parameterized URL indicates a collection of resources you select among using the parameters.

Comment: What sort of links do you think would be on the page indicated by that URL? if I put href="400000", on that page, what do you think would happen? how about href="../6.25/150000", contrast, linking from the amort_cal page to the account_summary page, would I use href="account_summary" or would I have to make it an absolute path? href="/account_summary". forward slashes are significant operators to the browser's relative URL resolver, so it's not a trivial design choice. I assume by the nature of the path segment names, that we *are* talking about a collection of resources to select from.

Comment: I mean, unless you'd actually sit down and create the million permutations that pattern suggests as static html files, we're talking about some kind of script that is taking parameters and generating a resource on the fly. The difference is that the slashes suggest a heirarchical relationship where I don't believe there is one, but the query is quite honest about what's going on, and even names what the different numbers mean, instead of leaving them unlabeled.

Comment: As for SEO, google does fine with query segments. That SEO stuff is an out of date myth.

Comment: Consider the principle of a referentially transparent function, where a call to the function can be replaced with its results without any change to the functioning of the program occurring. Consider how this is similar to a browser requesting a URL from a server, and then requesting the same URL from a local cache, or proxy. The only parameter the cache takes into account is the URL itself, as an opaque string. If you can see this similarity, then you can see that you can have a referentially transparent function as a server process, taking a query string as a parameter and returning a result.

Comment: And that this arrangement would be entirely in keeping with the rest architecture, as the output of this function would be cachable, and each of its results can be referenced as an individual resource.

Comment: "the million permutations that pattern suggests as static html files": Exactly every combination of "parameters" is a different resource as if someone precalculated every possible combination of amortization charts. That's why the URL should look like it points to a unique RESOURCE. We are talking about REST and REST is based on CRUDing RESOURCEs. The 6.25% compounded monthly 30yr fixed mortgage for $200,000 is a different resource than the 5.00% compounded monthly 15yr ARM for $100,000 and therefore has a different URL. I prefer not expressing that through parameters but by name.

Comment: REST is not based on "CRUDing Resources".  Sticking all your query parameters into path segments does not automatically make for a RESTful interface because now you think you can call every permutation a resource.  Unfortunately there is no magic process that you can apply to identify what the resources in your system should be.  It requires careful design, not a mechanical formula.

Comment: Once again, the REST architecture doesn't CARE what's in the URL. the URL is meant to be *opaque*. It doesn't matter to rest whether you use forward slashes, semicolons, or unicode hearts as seperators. Read this, and respond to this- not to what you imagine me to be saying.